# React-Redux useSelector has trouble passing data

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am using React with Redux. The Redux devtool console shows that data exists in the state ([redux devtools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuGMG.png)), but the webpage displays an error saying that the object is undefined ([error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBh2X.png)).

This is my code for my screen:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { listProductDetails } from "../redux/actions/productActions";

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProductDetails(match.params.id));
  }, [dispatch, match]);
  return <div>{product.name}</div>;
};

export default ProductScreen;
```

This is the code for my redux reducer:

```
import {
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants";

export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { product: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, product: action.payload };
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is the code for my action:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
      PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
      PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    } from "../constants";
export const listProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    });
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

I really cannot find the issue here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is when you dispatch `PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST` action, reducer will override the state value with `{ loading: true }`, and so `product` will be `undefined` instead of empty object `{}`.

So you should return merged object with the previous state in the reducer. e.g. `return { ...state, loading: true };`

Hope it could help you.

```js
export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { product: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, product: action.payload };
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```